# Error log with Apache2 , Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, webserver

```
[Fri Apr 13 11:53:26.575620 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4562] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 13 11:53:27.643379 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4680] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Apr 13 11:53:28.242660 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4681] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Apr 13 11:53:28.244700 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4681] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 13 11:53:28.244724 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4681] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 13 12:17:52.395246 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4681] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 13 12:17:53.469246 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4867] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Apr 13 12:17:53.491015 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4868] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Apr 13 12:17:53.493469 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4868] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 13 12:17:53.493501 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4868] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
root@localhost:/var/log/apache2# /usr/sbin/apache2
httpd (pid 4868) already running
root@localhost:/var/log/apache2# apache2ctl configtest 
Syntax OK
root@localhost:/var/log/apache2#
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? Do you expirience some problem with Apache?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, it's a warning message.

It's because your VirtualHost directive doesn't match your ServerName directive and/or the CN of the certificate. All three need to be identical, unless you have a wildcard certificate where the non-wild portions must be identical.

Comment: I want a solution for error 500 internal server  error

Comment: Then you need to ask a new question. Please include the error_log from the server, and what you are doing when you get the 500 error.